# How to turn sql into a transaction with multiple statements?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, transactions, prepared-statement

I have this sql which I run in php using pg_query_params. However, if I try to turn it into a transaction with BEGIN; and COMMIT; I get the following error: `Query failed: ERROR:  cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement`

Is it possible to prepare a transaction with multiple statements in the same query? Or how should I modify it to make a transaction?

Thanks!

```
WITH usr1 AS (
         SELECT id FROM users WHERE mongoid = $1
     ),
     usr2 AS (
         INSERT INTO users (mongoid, shopid, idinshop, attributes)
           SELECT $1, $2, $3, $4
           WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM usr1)
           RETURNING id
     ),
     ses1 AS (
         UPDATE sessions 
           SET traffic=$7, counts=$8 
           WHERE mongoid=$5 
           RETURNING id
     ),
     ses2 AS (
         INSERT INTO sessions (mongoid, shopid, userid, session, traffic, counts)
           SELECT $5, $2, (SELECT id FROM usr1 NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN usr2),
                  $6, $7, $8
             WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ses1)
         RETURNING id
     )

INSERT INTO events (shopid, sessionid, userid, type, attributes, mongoid) 
  VALUES (
      $2,
      (SELECT id FROM usr1 NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN usr2),
      (SELECT id FROM ses1 NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN ses2),
      $9, $10, $11
);
```

And then I run: `pg_query_params($db, $sql, array(...))`

Comment: Have you tried using PDO with emulated prepares instead?

Comment: Run each SQL statement as its own statement from PHP.

Comment: I'm not using PDO. I need a transaction, can't do different statements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `begin/commit` block. That whole statement is a transaction in itself

```
create table t (id int primary key);

with s as (
    insert into t values (1) 
    returning id
)
insert into t (id)
select id from s
;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

The CTE (`with...`) insert was rolled back:

```
select * from t;
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0eeef/2

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html):

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it.